# Sort list by the difference between two values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
         A           B         C                    D                
1                  Budget    Actual          Sort by Variancy (descending)
2     Product A     500       250                Product F
3     Product B     900       800                Product D
4     Product C     300       450                Product C
5     Product D     400       600                Product B
6     Product E     700       300                Product A
7     Product F     150       900                Product E
```

As you can see in **Column A** I have listed different products and in **Column B** I have their `budget` value and in **Column C** the `actual` value.

Now, I want to list  those products based on their `budget-actual-variancy` in **Column D** in a descending order (starting from the highest positive variancy).

The only formula which comes in my mind is `=LARGE(B2:B7,1)` but it only sorts the products by the `budget values` (**Column B**) or `actual values` (**Column C)**. Not by the difference between the two values.

Do you know any formula which I can use to sort the products in **Column D** based on their variancy?

---

**Please note:** 
I know I could add a `helper column` in which I calculate the differences between **Column B** and **Column C** and then go with the `LARGE` function on this `helper column` but I am looking for a solution without such a `helper column`.

---

Comment: As long as you don't have any duplicate variances then `=INDEX($A$2:$A$7,MATCH(AGGREGATE(14,3,$C$2:$C$7-$B$2:$B$7,ROW(1:1)),INDEX($C$2:$C$7-$B$2:$B$7,),0))` in `D2` will work

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I needed. Do you also have an alternative if the values are not unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following (even when there are duplicate variances):

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$7,LARGE(INDEX(($C$2:$C$7-$B$2:$B$7=AGGREGATE(14,3,$C$2:$C$7-$B$2:$B$7,ROW(1:1)))*($A$2:$A$7<>D1)*ROW($A$2:$A$7),),1))
```

Drag down.

In case of duplicate variances it will grab the last value in column A that represents that variancy and has not been featured in column D as yet.

Comment: Thanks a a lot. Any ideas for this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58462194/vlookup-with-multiple-criterias-in-different-columns?noredirect=1#comment103260575_58462194

Answer (score 1):

If one has SORTBY()(Currently only available with Office 365 insiders) then put this in D2 and it will spill automatically:

```
=SORTBY(A2:A7,B2:B7-C2:C7,1)
```

[image]